# How can you force a dump of a Go program on windows?

Tags: go, deadlock, dump

I'm looking to do some kind of debugging on windows where the state of the service appears to be a deadlock.  Perhaps the approach would be to do a dump.  How can you do a program dump of a Go service?  And then analyze that dump?

Comment: What do you mean by a "dump"? Do you want a stack trace or a core file?

Comment: I believe a core file.  I think I'd need the entire state in order to figure out a deadlock issue.  A stacktrace would likely depend on the time at which I caused the stacktrace.

Comment: A core file also depends on the state at the time you create it. A quick google points to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/241215. A stack trace is a lot easier way to show where each goroutine is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this using the [runtime.Stack](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Stack) function. Its output is equivalent to what you get from a panic(), but without halting the program. You can set up a signal handler to dump the stack to a file/stdout, or start a goroutine to dump the stack at regular intervals, if you prefer.

You could also check out the [runtime/debug](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#PrintStack) package.

Answer (score 0):

Goroutine deadlock analysis is handled well using the `trace` command.

First, you need to get data to run a trace against, which you want at any point. You can get this by using the `pprof` package or the `trace` package.

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/
https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/trace/

The `pprof` package will add its HTTP handlers to a web server and let you collect trace data while the app is running, while the `trace` package lets you write out a trace to a stream (e.g. a file), but I haven't tried that myself.

Once you've collected trace data, you can run the `trace` command against the data you've collected to produce a web view of the state:

https://golang.org/cmd/trace/

There's an example output here:

https://talks.golang.org/2015/dynamic-tools.slide#30